# Get subprocess.check_output to output mysql error

Tags: python, mysql, unix

I have the following code

```
def exec_sql_query(query):
    output = subprocess.check_output(
        [
            "mysql",
            "-h", config.sos.server,
            "-u", config.sos.username,
            "-p" + config.sos.password,
            "-D", config.sos.dataloaddatabase,
            "-sNL","--local-infile","-e",query
        ])
    return output.rstrip()

def email_notification_error(job_name, error_msg):

    server =  smtplib.SMTP(email_server)
    server.set_debuglevel(1)

    body = "<html><div>An Error has occured for job {0}.  Import did not complete.<br /><br />{1}</div></html>".fo$
    msg = MIMEText(body, 'html')
    msg['Subject'] = "Error Importing {0}. {1}".format(job_name, test_environment)
    msg['From'] = email_from
    msg['To'] = ','.join(email_to)
    server.sendmail(email_from,email_to,msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

#Main Entry Point
try
    exec_sql_query(refresh_query)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as ex:
    error_msg = "Error {0} running mysql query: {1}".format(ex.returncode, ex.output)
    logger.error(error_msg)
    email_notification_error(job_name, error_msg)
```

When it runs it sends out an email about the error. I get the email but all I get is

> An Error has occured for job JOB. Import did not complete.
>
> Error 1 running mysql query:

When I run the procedure in in an EDI (like Toad) I get

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

How can I get the MySQL error message in the EMail? It doesn't seem to be in `ex.output`.

> **Note** 
>   The error comes from my commenting out a field in an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query. I have done this on purpose to trigger the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subprocess.check_output() does not return stderr by default. As the doc string says:

```
The stdout argument is not allowed as it is used internally.
To capture standard error in the result, use stderr=STDOUT.

>>> check_output(["/bin/sh", "-c",
...               "ls -l non_existent_file ; exit 0"],
...              stderr=STDOUT)
'ls: non_existent_file: No such file or directory\n'
```

STDOUT is package relative, so you'd use subprocess.STDOUT.